# Trouble Reading numbers from a .txt file and arranging them into A-F grading, as well as finding max, min, and average numbers

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm a little stuck on actually getting the scanner to open the file I have and arrange the numbers. The computer tells me it recognizes the file I ask it to open, but then doesn't display the numbers. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much!

```
package helloworld;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class textToArray {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        //Open the file 
        File f = new File(" ");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Exam Statistics Program!");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );

        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file: ");

        String input = scanner.nextLine();

        //Create a new scanner to read the file
        Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
        //Declare an array with length of 100
        int[] array = new int[100];
        int i = 0, min, max, sum = 0;
        //Loop through the file if there is a next int to process it will continue

        for(i = 0; s.hasNextInt(); i++){
            //We store every int we read in the array
            array[i] = s.nextInt();                             
        }

        //Close the scanner object
        s.close();
        //As the for loop will stop when there is no new int to read so the i++ will stop at the number of int in the file
        //We use this number to calculate the average
        int nbInArray = i;
        //initialize min and max to the first array value which is for now empty
        min = max = array[0];
        for(int j = 0; j<nbInArray ; j++){
            //Now we test if the new value if bigger than the initial value (0 or empty) the new value will become the max
            if (array[j]>max){
                max = array[j];
                }
            //Otherwise if the the value is smaller than the initial value the new value will become the minimum
            //And so on every time we test if we have a smaller value the new one will become the min
            if (array[j]<min){
                min = array[j];
                }
            //The sum was initialised to 0 so we add every new int to it
            sum = sum + array[j];
        }


        //We compute the avg , i declared it double in case we have decimal results
        //double avg = sum / nbInArray;
        //finally we print out the min, max and the average
        System.out.println("The minimum is: "+min);
        System.out.println("The maximum is: "+max);
        //System.out.println("The averange is: "+avg);

}
}
```

Comment: Please post some example contents to be used as the input file, so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Not knowing what you are inputing it isn't possible to be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it! Change this line:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(input);
```

to:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(input));
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this was a big help. I found out another problem area was that I'm on a mac so I needed to specify the folder the document is in

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have to change some lines on your code:

```
    File f = new File(input);

//Create a new scanner to read the file
Scanner s = new Scanner(f);
```

You can also check that the user give you an existing file by using

```
  f.exists();
```

last advice a class name should start with a capital letter.